# Recognizing "complete" $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

**Disclaimer :** I asked a [very similar question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587039/characterizing-sets-of-nullsets-and-specialness-of-complete-sigma-algebras) two days ago.

---

Let $E$ be a set, let $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{F}$ be two $\sigma$-algebras on $E$, and let $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathcal{F}$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathcal{F}$.
Let us say that $\mathcal{X}$ is $\mathcal{E}$-**complemented** if
$$\forall X\in\mathcal{X},\exists~X'\in\mathcal{X},\quad X\sqcup X'\in\mathcal{E},$$

> **Definition.** An $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$-**null class** is an $\mathcal{E}$-complemented $\mathcal{F}$-[sigma-ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ideal).

For instance, if $\mu:\mathcal{E}\to[0,+\infty]$ is a non-negative measure on $E$, then the set
$$\mathcal{N}(\mu)=\lbrace N\subset E\mid \exists~N'\in\mathcal{E}, N\subset N'~\&~\mu(N')=0\rbrace$$
of $\mu$-negligeable sets is a $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{P}(E))$-null class.

Let us write,
$$U=\lbrace B\in\mathcal{F}\mid \exists~A\in\mathcal{E}, \exists~X\in\mathcal{X},~B=A\cup X\rbrace$$
for the set of all **U**nions of elements of $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{X}$, and
$$S=\lbrace B\in\mathcal{F}\mid\exists A,C\in\mathcal{E},A\subset B\subset C~\&~C\setminus A\in\mathcal{X}\rbrace$$
for the set of those $B\in\mathcal{F}$ that are **S**andwiched between two elements of $\mathcal{E}$ differing  by an element of $\mathcal{X}$. The following is elementary and well-known in the case of the [completion of a measure space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Measure_Spaces)) $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ :

> **Lemma.** If $\mathcal{X}$ is an $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$-null class, then
>   $$\sigma(\mathcal{E}\cup\mathcal{X})=U=S.$$

Yet I tend to find the equality $\sigma(\mathcal{E}\cup\mathcal{X})=U$ a striking result, seeing how complicated the description of the elements of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection of sets is in general (for instance [that of the Borel algebra of a metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Generating_the_Borel_algebra)).

---

### Questions :

1. Is there a characterization of those $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal E\subset\mathcal G\subset \mathcal F$ that arise as $\mathcal G=\sigma(\mathcal{E}\cup\mathcal{X})$ for an $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$-null class $\mathcal{X}$ ? Maybe in terms of lattice properties of the interval $[\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}]$ ?
2. Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is an $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{P}(E))$-null class. Does there exist a measure $\mu:\mathcal{E}\to[0,+\infty]$ such that $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{N}(\mu)$ ?

Comment: Don't you have an ideal, rather than a filter?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I think you are right, filters are usually upwards closed, while I demand downwards closure. I think I'll just write $\mathcal{F}$-closed.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The word I was looking for was "down set".

Comment: But it is closed under unions, so it is an ideal. Indeed, it is a $\sigma$ ideal.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, you are right. I'll modify the question accordingly.